# Qt using C++ or PyQT; which is mostly preffered for todays linux based embedded application development?

Tags: qt, user-interface, embedded, pyqt, embedded-linux

I spent few days to find out few open source application development libraries/tools for linux based embedded devices. I would like to know which one is mostly preferred in the industry. I understood that Qt is widely used for different embedded domains. Here are some other tools which I just came across

1. Gtk
2. Gdk-fb
3. NanoX

It seems Qt is good in documentation and python bindings are also available. I don't know whether python is really apt for embedded application development.

Any suggestion is really appreciated. Can I go for pyQT for Embedded Application/GUI development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Qt / C++ for an embedded system, if nothing else to avoid the overhead of having Python on the embedded system. Nowadays Qt 4 and 5 comes with JavaScript support - both directly and through QtQuick / QML. This would give you the flexibility of scripting, without bringing Python into the picture.

Beware, though, I'm an old geezer and probably have a view of embedded systems being far more memory constrained that the system that you are planning to use. If you can tell me more about the target hardware, I'm sure that I can help you with a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I have few ARM and X86 configuration in my mind; not decided the one yet; Thinking of Beagle board 1GHz with Sitara™ ARM® Cortex-A8 processor (Built-in 2GB storage with Angstrom).  Another one most probably based on Intel Atom x86.  Hope these boards can run Qt/C++ as well as python without much performance issues.

Comment: We'll, you're talking hundreds of megabytes of RAM, so Python should not be an issue, nor should C++. Happy hacking!